# Questions about typescript compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I have two questions about ts.

uncompiled code

```
class K {
  private p = 3;
  public q = 4;
  public r = () => {
    console.log(this.p, this.q);
  };
}

new K().r();
```

compiled code

```js
var K = /** @class */ (function() {
  function K() {
    var _this = this;
    this.p = 3;
    this.q = 4;
    this.r = function() {
      console.log(_this.p, _this.q);
    };
  }
  return K;
})();
new K().r();
```

#### 1. Why private variables become public after compilation?

I thought the code would be something like below to make q private. Why TS does not do it?

```js
var K = /** @class */ (function() {
  var p = 3;
  function K() {
    var _this = this;
    this.q = 4;
    this.r = function() {
      console.log(p, _this.q);
    };
  }
  return K;
})();
new K().r();
```

#### 2. What is the role of wrapping anonymous function?

If it does not use module pattern, anonymous function seems to be useless. The code could be like below I think.

```js
var K = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.p = 3;
  this.q = 4;
  this.r = function() {
    console.log(_this.p, _this.q);
  };
};
new K().r();
```

Comment: Please split your question post into two separate question posts- one for each question you have. Please also see [ask] for tips on how to write descriptive, non-ambiguous titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why private variables become public after compilation?

The idea of private properties *directly* on an instance is a very new one (using `#` syntax). There is no such keyword as `private` or `public` in actual Javascript. Declaring a property private or public in Typescript is there to *help you and others who read and use the code* understand how the code is meant to be used, but it doesn't make it *required*.

For similar reasons, you can write

```
window.fn = (arg: string) => {
  console.log(arg.slice(5));
};
```

and then, outside of the project, in Javascript, write

```
window.fn(5);
```

despite the fact that `fn` only accepts a string.

If you want to make the properties *actually* inaccessible from the outside, use `#`, eg:

```
class K {
  #p = 3;
```

This syntax is *extremely new* in Javascript, and is only supported in Typescript 3.8+. Eg

```
class K {
  #p = 3;
  public q = 4;
  public r = () => {
    console.log(this.#p, this.q);
  };
}

new K().r();
```

compiles to

```
"use strict";
var __classPrivateFieldGet = (this && this.__classPrivateFieldGet) || function (receiver, privateMap) {
    if (!privateMap.has(receiver)) {
        throw new TypeError("attempted to get private field on non-instance");
    }
    return privateMap.get(receiver);
};
var _p;
var K = /** @class */ (function () {
    function K() {
        var _this = this;
        _p.set(this, 3);
        this.q = 4;
        this.r = function () {
            console.log(__classPrivateFieldGet(_this, _p), _this.q);
        };
    }
    return K;
}());
_p = new WeakMap();
new K().r();
```

> 2. What is the role of wrapping anonymous function?

The whole creation of the class is encapsulated in an IIFE. Sometimes, this doesn't seem to do anything, but with some types of transpiled code, it helps prevent unnecessary scope leakage. Eg

```
class K {
  #p = 3;
  static foo = 'bar'
  method() {

  }
}
```

transpiles to

```
"use strict";
var K = /** @class */ (function () {
    function K() {
        _p.set(this, 3);
    }
    K.prototype.method = function () {
    };
    var _p;
    _p = new WeakMap();
    K.foo = 'bar';
    return K;
}());
```